# Application URL changes to GCLB domain name from the actual host

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, jboss, cloudflare-workers, google-cloud-load-balancer

Lets say user starts with https://www.example.com on the browser it goes via Cloudflare which intercepts the call and adds additional headers and calls GCLB end point. from there it in turn calls the app server. Now the issue is after the user does a successful login the domain is getting modified to "ui.dev.appname.lb.com" which is not expected. How to preserve the original hostname through out the user session.

Comment: Your backend code must preserve and use the correct hostname when it generates URLs.

Comment: what do you mean by preserve.Can you help me with the little more detailing.

Comment: 1) Configure a domain name for your server. 2) The web server uses that domain name when generating URLs. 3) How depends on details (code/configuration) not present in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.